# Make POST and GET request to JSON server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, json-server

I have a local json file which I am accessing data from. I have a text field and a button which gets populated by random entries from the file. The requirement is simple - on clicking the button, if I change the value of the text field, the same data should also be updated in the json file. How to do this?

I am using json-server to make the server-client connection but it is throwing below error -

GET http://localhost:3000/__rules 404 (Not Found) ( I don't know what __rules is here)

I simply ran the below commands from the vscode terminal-

1. npm install -g json-serevr
2. json-server --watch --api.json . (The json file and html file are in the same folder)

```
<html>
<body>
 <form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fetch">  
  </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$( document ).ready(function(){
  
  $.getJSON('api.json', function(data) {
            albums = data['Albums']
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)  ;
            $("#name").val(albums[num].Name);
            })
})

$('#fetch').click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault();
        var strname = $("#name").val();
        $.getJSON('api.json', function(data) {
          albums = data['Albums']
        $.post('api.json', function(data){
         albums[num].Name = strname 
        })
        })
        });
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
{
    "Albums": [
    {
        "Name": "Desire"
       
    },
    {
        "Name": "Essentials",
        
    },
    {
        "Name": "Hard Rain",
        
    },
    {
        "Name": "Blackstar",
        
    }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to make this work? I am not much aware of node.js or any other server side technology. I tried the above method and several others but nothing is working. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: should your route not be something like `"http://localhost:3000/Albums/"` instead of `"api.json"`

Comment: In this line, `num` is undefined due to the scope `albums[num].Name`

Comment: There are more problems in here but these seem like basic things to fix

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Exactly. I didn't understand what this route is ! And the other basic things I'll fix. num is to be declared globally. My priority was to get these GET and POST calls running first. The GET request works if I run on 8080 http server but POST fails. I just can't figure out how to update this data !

Comment: Only you know the port you have, looks like that component has 3000 by default but I have never used it